# #MAC operations in Convolution layer

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution

The formula for the number of MAC operations in CONV is given by *Filter_height * filter_width * In_channels * out_height * out_width * out_channels*.

I understand that multiplication and accumulation happens together every cycle. Does this formula also include the bias term addition?

Comment: What exactly is your question? 'What is the number of operations at each iteration?' ?

Comment: Well, I want to understand if the formula for MAC ops also includes the bias term addition.   

From what I understand, the number of operations = *((f_h * f_w * in_ch) + ((f_h * f_w * in_ch) - 1) * out_h * out_w * out_ch)* without bias term addition and *((f_h * f_w * in_ch) + (f_h * f_w * in_ch)) * out_h * out_w * out_ch)* with bias addition. 

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!